# Store an Image from registration page using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am using ExpressJS and NodeJS . 
I build a registration page which require from the user to upload his image.
the code in Jade

```
.form-container
h1 Create a User
form(name="adduser",method="post",action="/adduser")
  .col-xs-13
    p Username
    input.form-control(type="text", name="username")
  .col-xs-13
    p Email
    input.form-control(type="text", name="useremail")
  .col-xs-13
    p Upload an Image
    input.form-control(type='file', name ="pic", accept='image/*')
  .col-xs-13
    p Password
    input#password.form-control(type='text', name='pass',  required='')
  .col-xs-13
    p Confirm Password
    input#confirm_password.form-control(type='text',  required='' , onkeyup='checkPass(); return false;')
    span#confirmMessage.confirmMessage
  br
  .form-group
    button#myBtn.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") submit
```

i also have a script down there but its doesnt matter right now. 
the thing is i want to save the image in my Express Project directory but i am not sure how to do that. here is the code which store the other information in Mongodb DB , i just need to save the image now.

```
/* POST to Add User Service */
router.post('/adduser', function(req, res) {

    // Set our internal DB variable
    var db = req.db;

    // Get our form values. These rely on the "name" attributes
    var userName = req.body.username;
    var userEmail = req.body.useremail;
    var userPass = req.body.pass;

    var collection = db.get('users');

    // Submit to the DB
    collection.insert({
        "username" : userName,
        "email" : userEmail,
        "password" : userPass
    }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {

            res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
        }
        else {

            res.redirect("userlist");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
formidable = require('formidable'),
util = require('util'),
fs   = require('fs-extra'),
bodyparser=require('body-parser'),
qt   = require('quickthumb'),
path    = require('path');


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

var Images = require('./model.js');



app.use(qt.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use(bodyparser());
app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.post('/upload',function (req, res){ 

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  var userObj = [];
 form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      });

 form.on('field',function(name,value){
      // you will get the all the input field values here...
      console.log(name,value);//name gives input field name and value gives input value
      userObj.push({name:value});
  });



 form.on('end', function(fields, files) {

           //You can save the data into collection from the array
           //Images is my model
            var img = new Images();

            var temp_path = this.openedFiles[x].path;
           /* The file name of the uploaded file */
            var file_name = this.openedFiles[x].name;
            //console.log('file '+file_name);
            img.size = this.openedFiles[x].size;
            img.type = this.openedFiles[x].type;

            /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
            var new_location = 'uploads/';
               //to copy the file into a folder         
            fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err)       {  
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
           });//fscopy
         });//form end
res.send('Done!!');

});//post
app.listen(3000);
console.log('started server');
```

Answer (score 0):

For express use this.

> var formidable = require('formidable');
>
> npm i formidable

```
router.post("/one", (req, res) => {
 var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
 form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
     console.log(fields);
     console.log(files);        
     res.send(files);
 });
});
```